# How can i filter this Map correctly?

Tags: typescript, dictionary, filter, rxjs

i am having trouble filtering out objects from a stream. i just want a Map<string,{name: string}> with the test2 data to be returned...

```
import { filter, map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Observable, Observer, of, from } from 'rxjs';
import { fullObserver, setUpDOM, stream } from "./utils";


const data$: Observer<Map<string, {name: string}>> = of([
  ['test1', {name: 'test1'}],
  ['test2', {name: 'test2'}]
]).pipe(
    map((locAttrs) => Object.entries(locAttrs)
      // Array.from(locAttrs.values())
      .filter(([k, v]) => k !== 'test1')
    )
)
data$.subscribe((v) => {
  console.log('v', v);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right you wanna see something like this:

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

const data$: Observable<Map<string, {name: string}>> = of([
  ['test1', {name: 'test1'}],
  ['test2', {name: 'test2'}]
]).pipe(
  map((locAttrs) => {
    return locAttrs
      .filter(loc => loc[0] === 'test2')
      .reduce((prev, curr) => {
        prev.set(curr[0], curr[1]);
        return prev;
      }, new Map())
  })
)
data$.subscribe((v) => {
  console.log('v', v.get('test2'));
  }
);
```

1. You should replace `Observer` with `Observable`
2. Inside `console.log` you can get values by method `get` of `Map` object